# Ticking sounds in my screen recordings

Tags: audio-recording, audio, midi, audio-interfaces, daw

I have some issues with my home audio setup.

I use a Mac Book Pro and when it comes to gear I use Shure SM7B, DBX 286S, Scarlett 2i2, Screenflow to record screen, and Audio hijack to capture audio.

When I edit it I hear some random tick sounds. These are not for sure mouse click sounds.

I need some assistance in getting rid of them.

Here is a [sample of the tick sounds](https://www.kkteja.com/YEuXAxrR)

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been trying to figure this out but could for a year.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer under-run or clock sync issues.

There, that was easy to say… much harder to diagnose ;)
To over-simplify, both of those are reasons that the audio has to run to catch up all the time, meaning it occasionally skips a bit. Whenever that generates a rapid zero crossing in the audio waveform (in effect, a big sudden step rather than a sine wave), it will tick.

Buffer underrun happens when your machine is essentially "too busy to do all this at once".
Audio Hijack (& also most DAWs) has a setting to change the buffer size, sliding to the right increases latency by increasing buffer size, to the left decreases.

[image]

Clock sync issues tend to happen when one piece of software isn't running at exactly the same clock speed as another, so they constantly slip against each other. Multi-device setups in Audio Midi Setup have a switch to determine which should be the clock master, but I'm not sure I've ever seen anything like that in Audio Hijack. There is the possibility it's too 'consumer' & you might need to look at Loopback instead (or as well) to correct this.

In your DAW, you could probably zoom right into any tick visually & grab a screenshot of what the wave looks like at that exact point (dependant on audio software), which might give additional clues (or might not;).

If your software allows it, you could actually manually draw a new line at that point, making a less sharp transition. Quite often this will remove the tick entirely. It's not perfect, but tbh it can be good enough that no-one will ever spot it.

Things to test, in no particular order

- Increase buffer size in Hijack
- Try recording after a reboot, with nothing else running except what you need for the recording.
- Try recording audio without the screen capture running,
- Switch your Scarlett's input frequency in Audio Midi Setup, 44.1 or 48.
- Check you have latest hardware drivers for the Scarlett, & the latest macOS sub-version those drivers support. eg, if you're on 10.13, make sure it's 10.13.6
- Check you have the latest Hijack.
- Test without Hijack, just record into Quicktime.
- Test hijack under different file-type outputs, wav vs mp3 etc
- Test with mains connected & disconnected on the MBP.
- Check without going through the DBX (I doubt this will have any bearing, but you may as well be thorough.)

If I can think of any more, I'll add them.

I had a look at the wave in Cubase, which does show it as quite a complex interference rather than a single squared event - might be a sign that it happened before some other signal processing which  'smeared' the effect.

[image]

I managed to just about eliminate it by drawing out the worst of it. I had to go through a few sections to remove the 'smearing'

[image]

until I ended up with this…

[image]

which is now almost indiscernible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply. I can’t thank you enough for the info you provided.

I searched for the option that you have shown above in audio hijack and I was able to find it.

As of now, it's pointing to the extreme right on the scale (more reliable). You think that might be the reason for the clicks. Should I put it in the middle and do a sample recording to check if the ticking is gone?

Sorry for the lame questions, am not technical and I have been dreading to make changes in this audio software, don't know what's going to mess up what :P

Comment: You need to run tests, see which makes improvements, which doesn't. There was a list of 10 different things that may or may not work.